# Alternative to | more to display error results page by page

Tags: command-line

The command

```
psql -d template_postgis2 -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
```

returns a list of errors that is too long to be displayed by scrolling up to the beginning of the error.

I tried the same command with "`| more`" and "`| less`" added up at the end of the command but it does not display the message page by page as it should.

I also tried to put the output in a file with "`> file.txt`" but I do not get in this new file what is displayed on the screen!!

I don't understand why. I guess i can't do this with a psql command??
Is there any other way to get all the error message?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try terminal pager program (`pg`)?

Answer (score 4):

The errors which most of the programs print are sent to `stderr` (Standard Error) stream, whereas the output of the program is sent to `stdout` (Standard Output) stream.

Each stream has a **file descriptor**, which you can think of as a number which identifies a stream. `stderr` has file descriptor 2, and the value for `stdout` is 1.

- When you run

```
    command > file.txt
```

this is equivalent to running,

```
    command 1> file.txt
```

which has a meaning - *redirect the contents of `stdout` to the file `file.txt`*.

- However, if you want to redirect the contents of `stderr` only, you'd write:

```
    command 2> file.txt
```

- And to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr`, you'd either write:

```
    command &> file.txt
```

OR

```
    command > file.txt 2>&1
```

You can interpret the second command as - *Send the output of `command` to `file.txt`, and also merge `stderr` with `stdout`*.

- Similarly for sending errors to `less` or `more`, first merge `stderr` to `stdout` and then send it to the correspoding program.

```
    command 2>&1 | less
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to trap STDERR output to more/less or direct to a file, you need to tell it to do so. Simply using | or > will only grab STDOUT, and not STDERR. To grab both, you need to do something like:

`psql -d ... 2>1 | less`

This will redirect STDERR into STDOUT, and then both should appear in less when you are trying to page through the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think dobey and green7 have the better answers for your particular problem, but, for completeness:

I may get an error or message I didn't expect and not want to run the command again, or don't want to take the time. Therefore whenever I install a new operating system I start the gnome-terminal, go to Edit->Preferences->Scrolling Tab, and click the unlimited scrolling checkbox.

When using a kernel virtual console you can scroll back with Shift-PageUp.

When using less|more, or not using either, I sometimes find it easier to understand messages if I widen the terminal screen to be big enough horizontally to hold most of the message to eliminate line folding.